# Running a command in comment prompt from c#.net console application

Tags: c#-4.0, command-prompt

I just want to run a query with parameters in command prompt using c#.net code ?

and is it possible to copy the file from one path to another path through command prompt in c# code

waiting for your valuable commands

Comment: You seem to be confusing command and comment.

Comment: no i just want to execute some commands through c#.net code rather than manually entering in command prompt and executing it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[How to Execute a Command in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25983/How-to-Execute-a-Command-in-C)

[Useful commands](http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/tutorials/windows-command-prompt-introduction/)